# jQuery & Ajax combobox - different select tag names

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, combobox

I am practicing on [this](http://www.99points.info/2010/12/n-level-dynamic-loading-of-dropdowns-using-ajax-and-php/)

[here](http://demos.99points.info/ajax_dropdown/) is a working demo

here I may repeat the code:

### jQuery Code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#loader').hide();
        $('.parent').livequery('change', function() {
            $(this).nextAll('.parent').remove();
            $(this).nextAll('label').remove();
            $('#show_sub_categories').append('<img src="loader.gif" style="float:left; margin-top:7px;" id="loader" alt="" />');
            $.post("get_chid_categories.php", {
                parent_id: $(this).val(),
            }, function(response){
                setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function finishAjax(id, response){
      $('#loader').remove();

      $('#'+id).append(unescape(response));
    }
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="show_sub_categories">
    <select name="search_category" class="parent">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Categories --</option>
    <?php
    $query = "select * from ajax_categories where pid = 0";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>
    </select>   

</div>
```

### get_child_categories.php

```
<?php

include('dbcon.php');

if($_REQUEST){
$id = $_REQUEST['parent_id'];

$query = "select * from ajax_categories where pid = ".$id;
$results = @mysql_query( $query);
$num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($results);
if($num_rows > 0)
{?>
    <select name="sub_category" class="parent">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Sub Category --</option>
    <?php
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>
    </select>   
<?php   
}
else{echo '<label style="padding:7px;float:left; font-size:12px;">No Record Found !</label>';}
}
?>
```

It is N-Level dynamic loading of dropdowns (combo boxes) using jQuery, ajax and php which gets items from mySql database. everything goes fine but I have this in my HTML:

```
<select name="search_category" class="parent">...</select>  
<select name="sub_category" class="parent">...</select>  
<select name="sub_category" class="parent">...</select>  
<select name="sub_category" class="parent">...</select>
```

I want to have the selected items for every select tag , but as they have same name attribute values, I think I can not do it. please show me some way to change the names to sub_category1, sub_category2, ... or some other working way to do that.

Comment: please help me assign different ids like 1, 2, 3, ... to this select tags!

Answer (score 0):

This is the resolution I found:

I added this script after the last combo showing its contents:

```
$("#show_sub_categories select").attr("id", function(i) {
    return "combo_" + i;
});
```

put it in last else in get_child_categories.php
cheers!